# PowerBi Embedded and SQL Datewarehouse in different locations

Tags: azure, powerbi-embedded

I want to create Webapps with PowerBI Embedded from the german central datacenter. Unfortnuatly this service is not available and i don't know when it will become available.
Therefore my idea is to migrate PowerBi Embedded later and start with all other services located in german central. Is this possible or strongly recommended to have the PowerBi Embedded service and the azure SQL Datawarehouse in the same place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you place your data source (SQL Data warehouse) and your BI tool (Power BI) in different datacenters there are two things that should be mindful of:

**Latency and network speed** between the data centers may affect the performance of your BI solution significantly (in a negative way), especially if you are manipulating and analysing large amounts of data. It depends a little on how you set up your Power BI embedded. If you use DirectQuery then you will be hit with the latency penalty every time the query runs (whenever you look at your report), if not then you will only be hit with the latency when you refresh your imported data. However, without DirectQuery you may have to import more data in order to aggregate etc from the imported dataset.

**Egress**, you pay for traffic going *out* of data centers. If you continuously send large amounts of data between two data centers then the egress cost can be a factor for you. In a normal setup the traffic charges are almost negliable, but if your BI solution streams a lot of data on every refresh then it may build up to a lot of money.